# How to find the row and column of a certain string in a Google Spreadsheet through Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sheets, app-inventor

So I am trying to make a Google spreadsheet that records an ID and an amount. I would like to Input data through the Google web app script. This data will be an integer that will be used to find the row of the ID (The column will be given) in the spreadsheet. Then I want it to update the amount in the next column. Please help with this

I'm using MIT app inventor to get the ID
I have figured that part but this is where I'm struggling!

```
function searchString(){
  var search_string = id
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(search_string)
  var search_row = textFinder.findNext().getRow()
}
```

I tried using this code. Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. It doesn't look like your sheet is defined, so that'll be your first issue.

Try this:

```
function searchString() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YOUR_SHEET_NAME');
  var search = id;
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(search).findNext();
  var row = textFinder.getRow();
  var col = textFinder.getColumn();
  
  sheet.getRange(row, col+1).setValue('VALUE_HERE');
}
```

If you already have the column number, get rid of `var col` and replace `col+1` with your column number. These are indexed from 1, so A=1, B=2 etc. Here's an example:

```
sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue('VALUE_HERE'); //gets your row and column B
```

If not, `function searchString()` above will just get the next column along from the search string found.

I assume you already have the id part sorted out if you're using it as your search string?

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much! Only one question here sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue('VALUE_HERE');      What is the setValue for? And what should the value be? Thanks in advance

Comment: Disregard the top comment sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: No problem - please mark the answer as correct if this has solved your issue.